# Linked list concept in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, react-native

I am new to postgresql, can you please guide me about my query listed below?

I have a table in postgres (database) named "**app**" having two columns "**aid**" and "**cid**".

Table Name: **app**

**aid**   |  **cid**

a1 | a3

a2 | null

a3 | a5

a4 | a6

a5 | null

a6 | null

What I want to display(using sql query in server), when I select **"a1"** or **"a3"** or **"a5"** from **aid** using sql query, I want to list all values associated with **"a1"** and its child **cid** (in this case I want an output =  **a1 a3 a5**), its like a linked list **a1** is connected to **a3** and **a3** is connected to **a5**.

If I select **"a4"** using sql query, I need an output like this(**"a4 a6"**)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use recursion to accomplish this:

```
with recursive walk as (
  select aid, cid, array[aid] as path
    from app
  union all
  select w.aid, a.cid, w.path||a.aid
    from walk w
         join app a 
           on a.aid = w.cid
)
select *, array_to_string(path, ' ') as text_path
  from walk
 where cid is null;
```

[Working fiddle here.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2a6671443d85206e981966457387fe08)

If your table is large, then to limit the cost of recursion, use a `where` clause in the top half of the `walk` CTE to restrict your starting point.

```
with recursive walk as (
  select aid, cid, array[aid] as path
    from app
   where aid = 'a1'
  union all
. . .
```

You can get the reverse path without having to recurse again like this:

```
with recursive walk as (
  select aid, cid, array[aid] as path
    from app
  union all
  select w.aid, a.cid, w.path||a.aid
    from walk w
         join app a 
           on a.aid = w.cid
), forward as (
  select *, array_to_string(path, ' ') as text_path
    from walk
   where cid is null
), reverse as (
  select distinct on (a.aid) a.aid, f.path, f.text_path, r.path as rpath
    from app a
         join forward f
           on f.aid = a.aid
         join forward r
           on r.path @> array[a.aid]
   order by a.aid, array_length(r.path, 1) desc
)
select r.aid, r.path, r.text_path, 
       array_agg(u.rid order by u.rn desc) as up_path,
       string_agg(u.rid, ' ' order by u.rn desc) as text_up_path
  from reverse r
       join lateral unnest(rpath)
            with ordinality as u(rid, rn)
         on u.rn <= array_position(r.rpath, r.aid)
 group by r.aid, r.path, r.text_path;
```

[Updated fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=04061a3030ae102a809bbbdb4e0fabfa)

Comment: Mike, Thank you so much for your answer. This code is showing only forward path, I want to display backward path too. For Example: When I use [ where aid = 'a1' ] its output is [ a1 a3 a5 ] which is good, but when I use [ where aid = 'a3' ] it is showing [ a3 a5 ] only, I want to display forward and backward path too, like [a1 a3 a5 ] in case of [  where aid = 'a3'  ] . Can you do this for me?

Comment: This is truly awesome Mike, thanks. You are talking about cost of recursion, how would it compare if you tried to do the same thing in a Graph DB (like neo4js)?

Comment: @QuentinC  I am sorry, but I started looking into neo4j years ago and then gave up on it because my day job is focused on relational databases.  Recursion is necessary for less than 5% of the work I do, and the tools I feed data are built around the tabular data conceptual model.  Thank you for prompting me to have another look.  I will put it in my todo list.